# Select Data from Database Depend on Items in Listbox c#

Tags: c#, ms-access, listbox

I have a problem to select data depending on all items in a Listbox. Here, in my Listbox there are two items, named Kamera125 and Kamera127. Kamera125 and Kamera127 exist in a MS Access Database. So, when I run my program, I want my program to select Kamera125 and Kamera127 from listbox that connected to MS Access. I used the following query

```
string selectsemuakoordgaris = "select * from koordinatgaris where namakamera='" + listBox3.Text + "'";
```

and it doesn't work.

These is my codes :

```
            private void ProsesSemuaKamera()
            {
                Stopwatch watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

                Ping ping = new Ping();
                PingReply pingreply;

                OleDbConnection kon = new OleDbConnection(koneksi);
                OleDbCommand command = kon.CreateCommand();
                kon.Open();
                string selecturl = "select * from datakamera";
                command.CommandText = selecturl;
                OleDbDataReader bacadata = command.ExecuteReader();

                while (bacadata.Read())
                {
                    int counturl = 0;
                    pingreply = ping.Send(bacadata["ipadd"].ToString());

                    if (pingreply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                    {
                        listBox1.Items.Add(bacadata["ipadd"].ToString());
                        listBox3.Items.Add(bacadata["namakamera"].ToString());
                        textBox1.Text += bacadata["namakamera"].ToString() + Environment.NewLine;

                        CaptureSemuaKamera = new Capture(bacadata["urlkamera"].ToString());
                        Application.Idle += new EventHandler(ProcessFrameSemuaKamera);
                    }
                    else if (pingreply.Status != IPStatus.Success)
                    {
                        listBox2.Items.Add(bacadata["ipadd"].ToString());
                    }
                }
                kon.Close();

                watch.Stop();
                File.AppendAllText(@"D:\Dokumen\Alfon\TA Alfon\Waktu Eksekusi Ping.txt", "Waktu eksekusi ping " + DateTime.Now + " :" + " " + watch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
            }


            private void ProcessFrameSemuaKamera(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Image<Bgr, Byte> sourceImage = CaptureSemuaKamera.QueryFrame();
                SourceBox.Image = sourceImage.Bitmap;
ProsesSemuaKamera();
            }

            private void ProsesKameraSemua()
            {
                Image<Bgr, Byte> sourceImage = CaptureSemuaKamera.QueryFrame();
                SourceBox.Image = sourceImage.Bitmap;

                OleDbConnection kon = new OleDbConnection(koneksi);
                OleDbCommand commandkoord = kon.CreateCommand();
                OleDbCommand commandkoordgaris = kon.CreateCommand();

                kon.Open();

                string selectsemuakoord = "select * from koordinatkotak where namakamera='"+ listBox3.Items + "'";
                string selectsemuakoordgaris = "select * from koordinatgaris where namakamera='" + listBox3.Items + "'";
                commandkoord.CommandText = selectsemuakoord;
                commandkoordgaris.CommandText = selectsemuakoordgaris;
                OleDbDataReader bacakoord = commandkoord.ExecuteReader();
                OleDbDataReader bacakoordgaris = commandkoordgaris.ExecuteReader();

                while (bacakoord.Read() && bacakoordgaris.Read())
                {
                    #region Perspective projection

                    PointF[] srcs = new PointF[4];
                    srcs[0] = new PointF(int.Parse(bacakoord["x1source"].ToString()), int.Parse(bacakoord["y1source"].ToString())); //119, 187
                    srcs[1] = new PointF(int.Parse(bacakoord["x2source"].ToString()), int.Parse(bacakoord["y2source"].ToString())); //242, 181
                    srcs[2] = new PointF(int.Parse(bacakoord["x3source"].ToString()), int.Parse(bacakoord["y3source"].ToString())); //253, 225
                    srcs[3] = new PointF(int.Parse(bacakoord["x4source"].ToString()), int.Parse(bacakoord["y4source"].ToString())); //112, 231

                    PointF[] dsts = new PointF[4];
                    dsts[0] = new PointF(int.Parse(bacakoord["x1proj"].ToString()), int.Parse(bacakoord["y1proj"].ToString()));
                    dsts[1] = new PointF(int.Parse(bacakoord["x2proj"].ToString()), int.Parse(bacakoord["y2proj"].ToString()));
                    dsts[2] = new PointF(int.Parse(bacakoord["x3proj"].ToString()), int.Parse(bacakoord["y3proj"].ToString()));
                    dsts[3] = new PointF(int.Parse(bacakoord["x4proj"].ToString()), int.Parse(bacakoord["y4proj"].ToString()));


                    HomographyMatrix mywarpmat = CameraCalibration.GetPerspectiveTransform(srcs, dsts);
                    Image<Bgr, Byte> newImage = sourceImage.WarpPerspective(mywarpmat, 355, 288, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.INTER.CV_INTER_LINEAR, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.WARP.CV_WARP_FILL_OUTLIERS, new Bgr(0, 0, 0));
                    Image<Gray, Byte> newImageGray = newImage.Convert<Gray, Byte>();

                    Image<Bgr, Byte> imageToShow = newImage.Copy();
                    Image<Bgr, Byte> imageToShowGaris = newImage.Copy();

                    ProjectionBox.Image = newImage.Bitmap; //I want to show Projection result in ProjectionBox. All of coordinates are saved in database. When Kamera125 is choosen, all of coordinates in Kamera125 will be executed. So here, I want to execute all of coordinates of Kamera125 and Kamera127 that is shown in listBox.

                    #endregion
                }
                kon.Close();
            }
```

Comment: where you are executing query?

Comment: listBox3.Text is hardly the value that you should use in this query. You need to use the listBox3.Items collection. However your question is too unclear to give an answer. Why my code doesn't work and not providing the code is really useless. Please add the actual code that you are using in trying to select from the database

Comment: I have posted my codes below. Please help me.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for your advice :) Can you help me for my problem ? @Steve

Comment: Let me understand, you want to execute the _ProsesKameraSemua_ when there is an item selected in your listBox3 and retrieve information for that item right?

Comment: Almost. So here, I want to execute ProsesKameraSemua when there is item in my listBox3. For example, there are Kamera125 and kamera127 in my listBox, I want to retreive information from both of them without select one of them first. Other word, I want to retrieve information from Kamera125 and Kamera127 at a time.

Comment: And why do you create two datareaders for different tables? Does the koordinatkotak table  contain the names of all cameras? What is the purpose of the second reader that is not used anywhere?

Comment: Yaaa. For the first datareader I just want to get url of my cameras that are saved in datakamera table. For the second datareader, I want to get coordinates that are saved in koordinatkotak table. Both of that tables contain of namakamera. Namakamera is name of my cameras.

Comment: so if you were to type in the sql statement it would be written like: `select * from koordinatkotak where namakamera='Kamera125' OR namakamera='Kamera127'` So you would need to loop through your selecteditems and OR them together into a string and append that as your WHERE clause.

Comment: @CharlesMay - Yes that's what I mean but I don't know how to do that. Can you explain to me how to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's a simple method where you can pass in your listbox that has the items selected. It will return a string of the where clause built from the selected items.

```
    private string BuildWhereClause(ListBox lb)
    {
        string WHEREclause = string.Empty;
        foreach(var itm in lb.SelectedItems)
        {
            if (WHEREclause  == string.Empty )
            {
                WHEREclause += " WHERE namakamera = '" + itm + "' ";
            }
            else
            {
                WHEREclause += " OR namakamera = '" + itm + "' ";
            }
        }
        return WHEREclause;
    }
```

From this you can build your statement

`string selectsemuakoord = "select * from koordinatkotak " + BuildWhereClause(YourListBox);`

Comment: So, based on your code, my program will be working if I select one of items in my listBox ?

Comment: you can select none, one or many. It will build the WHERE clause based on what you choose. If you pass in a listbox with nothing selected, you will get an empty string back. Otherwise you will receive a where clause with your selections using OR between them.

Comment: Thanks Charles. I had tried to implement your code but it still doesn't work. My program can't do projection when Kamera125 and Kamera127 exists in my listBox. So, another word, my program didn't read and choose anything items in listBox

Comment: Wow ! Thanks Charles. That is something that I never known before. It works. Thanks so much :) I never realized before if there is a bit difference between giving a space after koordinatkotak and not. When I don't give a space after koordinatkotak it will be error and error says invalid argument. Can you explain to me why is it exist ?

Comment: If you didn't put a space after koordinatkotak your statement would have WHERE directly after it so your query would look like `select * from koordinatkotakWHERE...` that is why in the method I make sure to prefix a space so that it ensures a space is added before appending. If you copied and pasted my code you should be fine. If however, you typed it in then ensure you have a space before the WHERE and the OR so it appends properly. Don't forget to mark this question answered if it resolved your question.

Comment: Ahh I see. Thanks for a new knowledge you gave for me :) It really helps me and open my mind. Thanks a lot :)